# How to use getjson() for multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, json, getjson, jqxhr

I am trying to retrieve some JSON files. It is not certain which URL will work, therefore I am looking for a way to try all URLs and if one fails, it try another.

URLs like:

```
www.domain.com/a.json
www.domain.com/b.json
www.domain.com/c.json
```

```js
var url = "www.domain.com";
var file1 = "/a.json";
var file2 = "/b.json";
var file3 = "/c.json";

$.getJSON( url + file1, function( json ) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.users[ 3 ].name );
 });
```

Also the structure of each json file is not the same, so depending on the file i have to have a different way to access it. Let say for file `a.json` I will access data by json.users[3].name but in file `b.json` the same data will be accessed by `json.sources.users[3].name`.

So how can i make a such a method that try the new url whenever it fails? 
By failing, i mean it may be not existing file (404) or same groin policy error.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could chain the calls together, so if one call fails, it goes to the next using the jquery `fail` method on `$.getJSON`.  Something like this:

```
$.getJSON( url + file1, function( json ) {
    //do something with file1
}).fail(function () {
    $.getJSON( url + file2, function( json ) {
        //do something with file2
    }).fail(function () {
        $.getJSON( url + file3, function( json ) {
            //do something with file3
        })
    });
});
```

Link to docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jqxhr-object

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `Promise.all` implementation: [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
var url = "www.domain.com";
var urls = ["/a.json", "/b.json", "/c.json"];
var requests = urls.map(function(path) {
   return $.getJSON(url + path);
});

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(a_resp, b_resp, c_resp) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: ", a_resp, b_resp, c_resp );
});
```

This will allow you to wait until all requests have completed and give you access to all of their responses.